# igraph barabasi model with the possibility of a 2-way directed edge(in generation linking existing node to a future node)

Tags: python, igraph, directed-graph

I need to create a network where the graph generated can link an existing node (the node being generated) to one or more of the future nodes (the nodes that are going to be generated i.e. node_ID_future > node_ID_current) and not only to already generated nodes.

```
import igraph
N = 50
degree_mean = 5
m = list(np.random.poisson(degree_mean,N))
g = Graph.Barabasi(N, m, outpref=True, directed=True, power=1, zero_appeal=1, implementation="psumtree", start_from=None)
```

Below was my original code/model but I couldnt get it to run as my python.exe crashed every time. Im trying to get a model like the Barabasi model but is not limited to having directed edges only from a node of higher number to lower ones(ie node 2 can only have edges to node 1 or 0 {2->1 or 2-> 0} and node 20 to nodes lower than 20 but I need a directed node from eg 2-> 19 or 4->35)

```
N = 20
in_k = 3
out_k = in_k
indegree = np.random.poisson(in_k,N) #degrees for each node
outdegree = np.random.poisson(out_k,N) #degrees for each node
#lets create a storage array for the ID and col columns
columns = 3
shape = (N,columns)
a = zeros(shape)
ID = list(range(0, N, 1))

#Assigning the ID to col 1 and the degree to col 2

for k in range(0,len(ID)):
    a[k,0] = ID[k]
    a[k,1] = outdegree[k]
    a[k,2] = indegree[k]
def return_vertices(deg1_indices,deg2_indices,unused_indices,required_out): #function to choose edges based on degree and probability
    out_indices = zeros(required_out)
    pvals = [0.42,0.33,0.25] #probability of joining to 1deg, 2deg, or no degree node 
    iterations = int(required_out) 
    for h in range(0,iterations):
        chosen_type = np.where(np.random.multinomial(1,pvals))[0][0] #choose type from probabilities
        if (chosen_type < 1):
            type_options = len(deg1_indices)
            and_the_winner_is = np.random.randint(type_options) #choose random vertex of type selected
            out_indices[h] = (deg1_indices[np.random.randint(type_options)])

        if (chosen_type < 2) & (chosen_type >= 1):
            type_options = len(deg2_indices)
            and_the_winner_is = np.random.randint(type_options)
            out_indices[h] = (deg2_indices[np.random.randint(type_options)])

        if (chosen_type > 1):
            type_options = len(unused_indices)
            and_the_winner_is = np.random.randint(type_options)
            out_indices[h] = (unused_indices[np.random.randint(type_options)])

    return out_indices
#now we need to set up an adjacency matrix with the in and out degrees
#also i would like to add a higher probability of an edge Eji existing if there is an edge Eij

#Blank matrix for storage
A = zeros([N,N])

for i in range(0,N): #loop through vertices using rows as index
    #for j in range(0,N):
     if (A[i].sum() < a[i,1]): #if vertex needs outgoing edges

            if (A[:,i].sum() < 1): #if vertex is not receiving any edges, pick vertices at random
                edges_to_add = a[i,1] - A[i].sum()             
                Column_selected = np.random.randint(N,size=edges_to_add)
                A[i,Column_selected] = 1       

            if (A[:,i].sum() >= 1): #if vertex is receiving edges, higher probability of returning an edge based on degree
                edges_to_add = a[i,1] - A[i].sum()
                deg1_indices = nonzero(A[:,i]) #find 1st degree verts

                for l in range(0,len(deg1_indices)): #find 2nd degree verts
                    deg2_indices = nonzero(A[:,deg1_indices[l]])

                #non_degree_count = N - len(deg1_indices) - len(deg2_indices)
                print(type(deg1_indices[np.random.randint(1)]))
                #V_options = array([[zeros(len(deg1_indices))],[zeros(non_degree_count)]])
                used_indices = array([deg1_indices + deg2_indices])

                fitter_used = [None] * (N + 1)
                fitter_ID = [None] * (N + 1)
                for x in range(0, len(used_indices)):
                    fitter_used[x] = used_indices[x]
                for y in range(0, len(ID)):
                    fitter_ID[y] = ID[y]


                unused_indices = setxor1d(fitter_ID,fitter_used)
                #unused_indices = [2,5,9]

                the_chosen_ones = return_vertices(deg1_indices,deg2_indices,unused_indices,edges_to_add)
                for m in range(0,len(the_chosen_ones)):
                    A[i,the_chosen_ones[m]] = 1

#print(A)

conn_indices = np.where(A)
edges = zip(*conn_indices)
```

Im going to be working on this for the next week, so hopefully I will be able to post my own answer in the next couple of days.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include any code you have created to attempt to solve the problem. Also include the Current Input, desired output and current output.

Comment: If you define your own model, you'll probably need to implement it for yourself.

Comment: I see now that im going to have to design a new model, but my initial try has many issues as I was still leaning what the scope was. Thanks for the insight